# How to reference numpy array's columns?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I tried to reference a NumPy array as a python list.
This is what I tried

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print(np.shape(a))

print(np.shape(a[:2][:]))
print(a[:2][:])

print(np.shape(a[:][:2]))
print(a[:][:2])
```

Output:

```
(3, 3)

(2, 3)
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]

(2, 3)  # expecting (3,2)
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]  # expecting [[1 2],[4 5], [6 7]]
```

Comment: e.g. `a[:, :2]` for the last

Answer (score 0):

Nvm,

I should use `[x,y,z]` instead of `[x][y][z]` for numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

`a[:]` returns the entire 2D-array `a`. Thus, your code `a[:][:2]` is interpreted as `(a[:])[:2]` which is the same as `a[:2]`.

In NumPy, the different dimensions are accessed within the same brackets, separated by commas. Hence, your two examples should be:

```
print(np.shape(a[:2, :]))      # or just a[:2]
print(a[:2, :])

print(np.shape(a[:, :2]))
print(a[:, :2])
```

which yield the expected output.

Comment: I figured this out, but still, thank you so much for helping out with this simple question!!